# All code intelligence in Block and nothing in Controller?

Tags: php, blocks, controllers, magento-2.1, best-practice

Is it a good practice in Magento CE 2.1 to put all code intelligence of a module in Blocks and leave the Controller almost empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283920/magento-model-vs-block-vs-controller-etc),

> Block are responsible for rendering content (everything from frontend, backend, emails, and more). If content is being displayed somewhere chances are it is a block.
>
> controllers are responsible for processing all requests made via a url. If you hit the url http://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/9/ you hit the catalog module in the controllers/ProductController.php and inside of that the viewAction() method. If you hit a URL in Magento the request passes through one or more controllers.

Also, this topic can help you understand the concept of a Block:
[Why does Magento need blocks?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131292/why-does-magento-need-blocks)